# Java class hierarchy refactoring without changing the invoking code, is it possible?

Tags: java, dynamic, javassist, cglib

Current situation:

in a Java system, we have a class named Passenger as below, let's say,

```
public Class Passenger{
//lots of member fields
private String firstName ;
private String lastName ;
private WhatEverAttribute att;

//lots of getters & setters
WhatEverAttribute getAtt(){ return att;}
void setAtt(WhatEverAttribute attIn){ this.att=attIn;}
...

//and lots of methods,for example
List<String> doWhatEverFuction(...){ return ... }
...
}
```

And in the application elsewhere there are a many places will create and use this class as:

```
Passenger p1 = new Passenger();
p.setFirstName("blablabla")
p.setAtt(xxx);
Passenger p2 = new Passenger();
p2.setAtt(yyy)
List retl = p2.doWhatEverFuction(...);
...
```

The system previously only manage Air/Flight passengers, so the Passenger
class is actually data model for air passengers,

Now the problem is,  we need to extend the model and make a hierarchy, as the Passenger will be a generic Passenger model, holding common fields and functions, new model AirPassenger and SeaPassenger will extend it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB8Is.png)

So some common fields and functions will be kept 
in Passenger to share between AirPassenger and SeaPassenger, but most air passenger specific fields and functions will be pushed down to AirPassenger,

then everybody knows that I have to change the existing code accessing Passenger from

```
   Passenger p = new Passenger();
   p.xxxxxx();
```

to

```
   AirPassenger p = new AirPassenger();
   p.xxxxxx();
```

There are so many places and I don't want to manually change them in many places in existing code accessing Passenger from the whole application,

What I want is after making the hierachy, the rest of the code still working without any changes, by utilizing some tricks of technics, I could return 
an AirPassenger through the new Passenger() constructor like:

```
Passenger{

Passenger(){

return Passenger("Air")

}

Passenger(String type){
  Switch(type){
  ...
  case "Air": return new AirPassenger();
  ...
  }

}

}
```

**by some dynamic features of Java, CGLIB or whatever, is it possible?**

Comment: What IDE are you using? Normally the IDE should help you with that

Answer (score 1):

The approach you end up choosing will depend on many factors, largely how and where your code is being used. If all usages of this class are accessible to you, I would highly advise against your proposed solution - a proper inheritance hierarchy would help keep your code organized and make it possible to easily expand your program in the future. Many IDEs (e.g IntelliJ) offer **great** functionality for smart-refactoring of your code and extraction to new classes, that will do almost all the work automatically and ensure the code keeps running as intended.

If possible, your situation is a classic case for the use of an abstract parent class. Since there is no such thing as a "general passenger", a more correct design for your hierarchy would be to declare Passenger as an abstract class. This way instances of Passenger cannot be created directly, but the class itself can hold implementations which inheriting classes can use or override as necessary.
You can also add a factory method to this class, which will return a new Passenger of the correct type, according to input (as you suggested).

**Edit:**

Polymorphism and class hierarchy work in Java in a very particular way. That is, some limitations are put on the programmer to maintain code readability and modularity.
What you have asked for (in your clarification comments) is not possible in the way you are describing.

You create two new classes:

```
class AirPassenger extends Passenger {

    ...

    public void doSomethingAir() {
    ...
    }

    ...
}

class SeaPassenger extends Passenger {
    ...

    public void doSomethingSea() {
    ...
    }

    ...  
}
```

You refactor some of its methods into the new AirPassenger class and leave some where they are. 
The first thing you will notice, is that you **cannot use the existing Passenger constructor** to return instances of AirPassenger or SeaPassenger, since a constructor is a
void method and has no return value. You will therefore need to provide some construction Factory method to create instances of either AirPassenger or SeaPassenger.

```
    Passenger createPassenger(String passengerType) { 
        switch (passengerType) {
            case "sea":
                return new SeaPassenger();
            default:
                return new AirPassenger();
        }
    }
```

You refactored methods out of Passenger and into AirPassenger. These methods no longer exist in the Passenger class, and they cannot be called by Passenger objects.
You **can** however use explicit type casting to re-cast all Passenger objects to AirPassenger, and then you will be able to use all the methods which are now in AirPassenger. 
This can also be done using a single method:

```
AirPassenger convertToAirPassenger(Passenger passenger) {
    return (AirPassenger) passenger;
}
```

Comment: My goal is,  after I refactor the model, the old code like:    Passenger p = new Passenger();
   p.xxxxxx();    is still working, while the method xxxxxx() now is inside AirPassenger, not in Passenger any more, is it possible? with some advance topics of dynamic features of Java, or CGLIB ?

Comment: I think the above solution would be your best bet in this case.
However note that explicit type casting is generally a big no-no in Object Oriented Programming, and should only be used sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

Of course I can find & replace, and most IDE can do it, 
but problem is in the system there are some configuration file, and txt file, work as dictionary, and templates you know, they use the Passenger word or add prefix and suffix, or lower case, you know, you can not just find and replace, so not only Java code changes needs to be made, so I would rather not change them if there is a way, that is my question.

```
//you create an instance of class
ClassA obj = new ClassA();
//you call method doIT() inside ClassA
obj.doIt();
```

Now I have to re-model it as ClassA becomes a superclass, and those methods push down into its subclass, let's say ClassB, so **ClassB extends ClassA, method doIt() is inside
ClassB now**,
everyone knows as usual I need to change the above code to

```
//you create an instance of ClassB, 
ClassB obj = new ClassB(); 
//or ClassB obj = new ClassA(); you have little code in the ClassA constuctor, etc.
//then you call a method
obj.doIt();
```

I know that, but **my question is**, without make changes to it

```
ClassA obj = new ClassA();
obj.doIt();
```

is there any tricks that will make it works with the new model?

Comment: Just a note - next time you have information to add/change, edit your original post instead of answering your own post. This is generally frowned upon in the SO community.